# Speedup of calculation for symmetric matrix using OMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, transpose, matrix-multiplication, intel-fortran

My matrix calculation is: C=C-A*B

Here C is a symmetric matrix so I want to speed up this calculation by considering just the upper triangular and then take the opposite elelement. I used OMP and see that my implementation is slower than the normal calculation for the entire matrix C.

I also see that the calculation for C=C-AxB is slower than C=C+AxB.

My program is attached. Please advise me!

```
    Program testspeed
implicit none
integer nstate,nmeas,i,j,l
integer(kind=8) :: tclock1, tclock2, clock_rate
real(kind=8) :: elapsed_time
double precision, allocatable, dimension(:,:):: B,C,A
nstate =20000
nmeas=10000
allocate (B(nmeas,nstate),C(nstate,nstate),A(nstate,nmeas))
A=1d0
B=1d0
call system_clock(tclock1)
write(*,*) "1"
!$omp parallel do
do j = 1, nstate
    do l = 1,nmeas
        do i = 1, j
            C(j,i) = C(j,i) - A(j,l)*B(l,i)
            C(i,j)=C(j,i)
        end do
    end do
end do
!$omp end parallel do
write(*,*) "2"
call system_clock(tclock2, clock_rate)
elapsed_time = float(tclock2 - tclock1) / float(clock_rate)
write(*,*) elapsed_time
end Program testspeed
```

Comment: From a quick look it seems you have a race condition. Think what elements you are accessing in your parallel loop.

Comment: You also seem to have chosen the worst possible loop ordering that could be devised. But use BLAS for this. Seriously. The factor of 2 you are trying to save will easily be beaten by a optimised BLAS routine.

Comment: Also you are setting the transposed element `nmeas` times, when you only need to do it once.

Comment: You also need to initialise `C` before you use it

Comment: @VladimirF I thought that at first glance, but on re-reading it is OK. Each thread will have a separate value for j once the outer loop is workshared, and so no two threads will write to the same C( i, j ) or C( j, i )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the basic rules I have taught my students is that nobody should be writing dense matrix multiplies themselves nowadays - and should not have been doing for 30 years +. You should use the BLAS library instead. Below I compare using the BLAS library against your loop ordering and a better loop ordering, and also against the Fortran intrinsic function `matmul` which I use as a reference to check the results are correct. BLAS and `matmul` don't take advantage of the symmetry of C, yet they still are the fastest routines - BLAS is about 200-300 times quicker than the loop ordering you have written. Note I have also cut the matrix size down somewhat as I got bored waiting for the original to run for larger cases:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat mm.f90
Program testspeed

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64, li => int64

  Use omp_lib, Only : omp_get_max_threads
  
  Implicit None
  Integer nstate,nmeas,i,j,l
  Integer(li) :: tclock1, tclock2, clock_rate
  Real(wp) :: elapsed_time
  Real( wp ), Allocatable, Dimension(:,:):: B,C,A
  Real( wp ), Allocatable, Dimension(:,:):: C_test
  Real( wp ), Allocatable, Dimension(:,:):: C_start

  Write( *, * ) 'Using ', omp_get_max_threads(), ' threads'
  
!!$  nstate =2000
!!$  nmeas=1000
  nstate = 5000
  nmeas  = 2500
  Allocate (B(nmeas,nstate),C(nstate,nstate),A(nstate,nmeas))
  Allocate( C_test, Mold = C )
  Allocate( C_start, Mold = C )
!!$  A=1.0_wp
!!$  B=1.0_wp
  ! Random numbers are a much better test
  Call Random_number( A )
  B = Transpose( A ) ! make sure result is symmetric
  Call Random_number( C_start )
  ! Make Initial C Symmetric
  C_start = 0.5_wp * ( C_start + Transpose( C_start ) )

  Write( *, * ) 'Matix sizes ', Shape( A ), Shape( B ), Shape( C )
  
  C_test = C_start
  Call system_Clock(tclock1)
  C_test = C_test -  Matmul( A, B )
  Call system_Clock(tclock2, clock_rate)
  elapsed_time = Real(tclock2 - tclock1,wp) / Real(clock_rate,wp)
  Write( *,'( a, t20, f8.3 )' ) 'Matmul', elapsed_time

  C = C_start
  Call system_Clock(tclock1)
  !$omp parallel do
  Do j = 1, nstate
     Do l = 1,nmeas
        Do i = 1, j
           C(j,i) = C(j,i) - A(j,l)*B(l,i)
           C(i,j)=C(j,i)
        End Do
     End Do
  End Do
  !$omp end parallel do
  Call system_Clock(tclock2, clock_rate)
  elapsed_time = Real(tclock2 - tclock1,wp) / Real(clock_rate,wp)
  Write(*,'( a, t20, f8.3, t30, "Max error ", g20.12 )' ) &
       'Orig loops', elapsed_time, Maxval( Abs( C_test - C ) )

  C = C_start
  Call system_Clock(tclock1)
  !$omp parallel default( none ) shared ( nstate, nmeas, A, B, C ), private( i, j, l )
  !$omp do 
  Do i = 1, nstate
     Do l = 1,nmeas
        Do j = 1, i
           C(j,i) = C(j,i) - A(j,l)*B(l,i)
        End Do
     End Do
  End Do
  !$omp end do
  !$omp do
  Do i = 1, nstate
     Do j = 1, i
        C( i, j ) = C( j, i )
     End Do
  End Do
  !$omp end do
  !$omp end parallel
  Call system_Clock(tclock2, clock_rate)
  elapsed_time = Real(tclock2 - tclock1,wp) / Real(clock_rate,wp)
  Write(*,'( a, t20, f8.3, t30, "Max error ", g20.12 )' ) &
       'Sensible loops', elapsed_time, Maxval( Abs( C_test - C ) )

  C = C_start
  Call system_Clock(tclock1)
  Call dgemm( 'N', 'N', nstate, nstate, nmeas, -1.0_wp, A, Size( A, Dim = 1 ), &
                                                        B, Size( B, Dim = 1 ), &
                                               +1.0_wp, C, Size( C, Dim = 1 ) )
  Call system_Clock(tclock2, clock_rate)
  elapsed_time = Real(tclock2 - tclock1,wp) / Real(clock_rate,wp)
  Write(*,'( a, t20, f8.3, t30, "Max error ", g20.12 )' ) &
       'BLAS ', elapsed_time, Maxval( Abs( C_test - C ) )
  
End Program testspeed
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -std=f2018 -O3  mm.f90 -lopenblas
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Using            1  threads
 Matix sizes         5000        2500        2500        5000        5000        5000
Matmul                4.793
Orig loops          421.564  Max error   0.488853402203E-11
Sensible loops       20.742  Max error   0.488853402203E-11
BLAS                  2.185  Max error   0.682121026330E-12
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Using            2  threads
 Matix sizes         5000        2500        2500        5000        5000        5000
Matmul                4.968
Orig loops          324.319  Max error   0.466116034659E-11
Sensible loops       17.656  Max error   0.466116034659E-11
BLAS                  1.161  Max error   0.682121026330E-12
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=3
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Using            3  threads
 Matix sizes         5000        2500        2500        5000        5000        5000
Matmul                4.852
Orig loops          243.268  Max error   0.500222085975E-11
Sensible loops       15.802  Max error   0.500222085975E-11
BLAS                  0.852  Max error   0.682121026330E-12
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Using            4  threads
 Matix sizes         5000        2500        2500        5000        5000        5000
Matmul                4.994
Orig loops          189.189  Max error   0.477484718431E-11
Sensible loops       14.245  Max error   0.477484718431E-11
BLAS                  0.707  Max error   0.682121026330E-12
```

For BLAS I have used openblas - which is freely available. On Linux system a simple apt get or similar should be enough.

Please also note

1. If you have to write your own loops your inner most loop should go, if possible, over the first index of your array. This is because Fortran orders its arrays as column major. This is what I have done in the "sensible" loop ordering
2. `Real( 8 )` is not portable, not guaranteed to be supported by your compiler, and not guaranteed to do what you expect, and shouldn't be used. Similar for `Integer( 8 )`. Please see what I have done for a better way that should work with all compilers.
3. `Float` is not a standard intrinsic - use `Real` as I have done
4. As benchmarks are meaningless if the results are incorrect you should always include a way to test the results. Here I use the Fortran intrinsic `matmul` to provide a reference version. Your original code does not initialise C, so the results can not be trusted - but as you don't check you get the correct values for C you can't know this.
5. I personally dislike `!$omp parallel do` intensely, I think it a mistake that such short cuts are in OpenMP. Instead separate them into `!$omp parallel` and `!$omp do` - it is very important to understand that thread creation and work sharing are different things, convoluting them in one line is not a good way to learn OpenMP.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I tried on my computer using 20 threads. Blas routines is 80% faster than the Matmul. It's not so significantly reduced as yours results. I used visual studio with Maximize Speed plus Higher Level Optimizations (/O3) and MKL parallel options. I wonder is there any way I can improve the speed significantly like yours in visual studio?

Comment: Not nearly enough information to tell. Are the BLAS results roughly the same speed as mine? If yes, then you probably can't make it any quicker. If no you need a better BLAS.

Comment: Trivial, I know, but you have "Matix sizes" (Since this is an answer I'll want to point more people at it seems worth fixing even though it is trivial.)